# Insert PDF File Content as varbinary(MAX)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I post my file over my form.

After that i store the content in $content

```
    $extract = fopen($tmp_name, 'r');
    $content = fread($extract, $size);
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($extract);
```

now i want to know how to store $content in my SQL Field with type varbinary(MAX)

With this it doesnt work.

```
                $docsql = "INSERT INTO DOKUMENT (
                        Typ,
                        Dateiname,
                        Dokument,
                        JournalID 
                    ) VALUES (
                        2,
                        :Dateiname,
                        :Dokument,
                        :JournalID
                    )";

                $d = $db->prepare($docsql);
                $d->bindParam(':Dateiname', $filename);
                $d->bindParam(':Dokument', $content);
                $d->bindParam(':JournalID', $journalID);
                $de = $d->execute();
```

The error is, that it wasnt the correct format for this field, any ideas?

Comment: Assuming that you are using PDO, this could help: [Handling Binary Data with PDO](http://jeremycook.ca/2010/02/21/handling-binary-data-with-pdo/). But this is not the best approach. Storing files in database is not a best practice. If you can, store the path to the file instead of the binary data. SQL Server is not a document store.

Comment: I know but i need to store it to my database because i open this "file" which is stored in this tabel a REP System... So i need to do it like i said @Pred

Comment: who's throwing the error? php, the webserver or sql? please share the actual error message.